# How to set property of model in controller - yii

Tags: php, yii, model, controller

I'm attempting to set a property value of a model within the controller to be accessed later. In my index I have

```
public function actionIndex($id)
{
    $model = new Recipient;
    $model->listId = $id; 
    ActiveDataProvider('Recipient', array('criteria'=>array(
                                            'condition'=>'list_id = '.$id)));
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'id'=>$id
    ));
}
```

and then in the model I would like to use that listId so I have

```
public $listId; 

// before you save the function here are the things you should do
public function beforeSave()
{
    if($this->isNewRecord)
    {
        // updates the list_id of the individual with the passed in listId
        $this->list_id = $listId;


    }
    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Now this model function will be called before I use actionCreate in the controller (not actionIndex). Is there still a way to keep that variable as is in the controller and then call it in the model? The other option that I've been toying with is to pass the $id from the view in the index into the view in the create. But, I don't feel like I should be passing too much data around in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several issues:

1) You create a new instance of Recipient in `actionIndex` but never use it anywhere. Hence  [Sardor's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24694744/428543) to remove those lines.

2) You are using `$id` and `listId` to refer to the same thing. You should use `$listId` instead.

3) You have to keep the value of `listid` between application instances. You could set a session variable but this is a terrible idea (you'd have to set and clear it carefully). A better solution is to pass the `listid` to the view and back to the controller as a `POST`/`GET` parameter.

If you are worried about sending too much data, you could always pass `listid` as a `POST` parameter instead. You could then set it in the controller using `$model->listid = $_POST['listid']`.

Another solution would be to encrypt the get parameter when creating the url and decrypting it in your `actionCreate`

Comment: If you are saying that $model = new Recipient is not being used, then what is happening when I call $model->listId = $id? Is this not referring to the new Recipient that I created?

Comment: What I mean is that all that is being done is that the `listid` is set. `$model` isn't being saved, referenced anywhere or passed into the view therefore it is of no use.

Comment: Ah, okay so I would need to save the $model if I wanted to use it anyways - so it is empty code in this instance. And this is true even though I try to use it in the "beforeSave" function?

Answer (score 1):

You must  remove these lines in actionIndex:

```
$model = new Recipient;
$model->listId = $id;
```

Comment: But the whole point of having those lines is so that  I set what listID is? If I don't have those lines how can I set what the listId is in the model? That just means I would have a variable in the model that hasn't been touched

Comment: But, you didn't use $model in actionIndex, it mean nothing. You only creted new object, and set $model->listId = $id; but, you didn't sent $model  to view .